# passport.use local-login acess to res

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I am having difficulty passing the res var to a passport autheticate middleware module.

Following the passport guide: http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/
it states that to pass the res to the authenticate method to enable a custom redirect you need to place the `passport.authenticate` into the app.post callback.

As i want to keep all the business in my passport file, and not in the routing i came up with the following:

The route:

```
// process the login form
app.post('/login', function( req, res, next ){

    console.log(1);

    passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
        failureFlash : true
    });
});
```

The module:

```
....
// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {
   ....
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) { 

            console.log(2)

            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
                if (err){
                    return done(err);
                }

                console.log(3)

                // if no user is found, return the message
                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

                if( !user.local.authenticated )
                    return res.redirect( '/resend-activation/' + user.local.email );

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, user);
            });

        }));
```

However the logs from a post to this route is:

```
server-0 (out): 1
server-0 (out): POST /login 200 120002ms
server-0 (out): 2
server-0 (out): POST /login 200 120090ms
```

Thats it. It never hits the `console.log(3);`

I'm not really sure what i am doing wrong here, is it because the `req` in the app.post callback is overwriting the `req` in the passport.auth?

Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks.

john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems i am might have just found the answer.. i don't know how that happens sometimes.. you write the Q post it the you have a eureka moment..

First up I missed off the parenthesis to actually run the auth function so i updated to the route:

```
app.post('/login', function( req, res, next ){
        passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/login', 
            failureFlash : true
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

Then in the auth passport i printed all the arguments being passed and noted that the res was in the req. So performing a custom redirect worked like this: `req.res.redirect...`:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true        },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        console.log( arguments.length );
        console.log( arguments );

        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            console.log(123);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 

            if( !user.local.authenticated )
                return req.res.redirect( '/resend-activation/' + user.local.email );

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));
```

I don't know though if this is a proper way of doing things or not..?